# how to run batch file from java code?

Tags: java, windows

I've tried the following codes but nothing happens.

```
List cmdAndArgs = Arrays.asList({"cmd", "/c", "simple.bat"});
String dir ="E:\\SK\\EXTRA KNOWLEDGE\\JAVA\\RUN OTHER APP";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdAndArgs);
pb.directory(new File(dir));
Process p = pb.start();
```

and

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?(just to make the question more clear)

Comment: i just want to run my own batch file from java code. batch file may contain any of commands of DOS like 'date' 'time' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start YourBatch.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe", "/c", "./users/batch.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "simple.bat"});
```